# Why is using an identifier not in scope UB and not an error

Tags: c, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, c89

I quote from the ANSI_ISO+9899-1990, in the list of all Undefined Behaviors -

> - An identifier is used that is not visible in the current scope

Why is use of undefined variable UB and not an error? I want to know the reasoning behind this? Is it valid to make everything that is not "correct" as UB?

I know most of the compilers treat it as errors. But why does the standard say this?

Or there is no notion of "error" in the standard?
The grammar of c is .* but some part of it has UB?

Comment: When reading technical standards, you must separate normative text from informative text. Normative text that must be followed, while informative text is just provided for clarification.The quoted text comes from an informative appendix. It is not normative text and not something compilers have to follow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is very much a concept of errors in the standard, it's just that not everything counts as an error. I'll say two things up front which may help you out here:

1. C89/90 was to codify *existing* practice, *not* to create a new language. That means it was sometimes necessary to compromise on things even when they didn't make sense.
2. C99+ did *not* have that restriction so certain things were able to be cleaned up. In fact, since that text you quote appears to disappear in C99, this may well be one of the things cleaned up.

Back to the reasoning, the ANSI C89 rationale document has this to say:

> One source of dispute was whether identifiers with external linkage should have file scope even when introduced within a block.  The Base Document is vague on this point, and ***has been interpreted differently by different implementations***. For example, the following fragment would be valid in the file scope scheme, while invalid in the block scope scheme:

```
typedef struct data d_struct ;
first(){
    extern d_struct func();
    /* ...  */
}
second(){
    d_struct n = func();
}
```

> While it was generally agreed that it is poor practice to take advantage of an external declaration once it had gone out of scope, some argued that a translator had to remember the declaration for checking anyway, so why not acknowledge this?  ***The compromise adopted was to decree essentially that block scope rules apply, but that a conforming implementation need not diagnose a failure to redeclare an external identifier that had gone out of scope (undefined behavior).***

It's almost certainly that phrase "has been interpreted differently by different implementations" which caused them to mark it as UB rather than an error. And note that it's not the *scope* that is in question here, just whether an implementation needs to report the fact you're trying to use it.

Comment: Okay, scopes of external linkages still seem debatable, I agree with that. But why does use of undefined variable (identifier in general) not qualify as error? Is it just one of the compromises they made at that time. It is relieving to know that it doesn't appear in C99. I don't have the copy.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya C99 at http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html, C11 at http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links. I will be sure to book mark them.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya There are other sources but these two have inline anchors to each paragraph.

Comment: I hope accessing these sources do not violate any copyright because I would mostly need them in the office.

Comment: I ask this because all the PDF downloadable versions ask me to pay.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya These are drafts and not the actual standards. You can find the drafts available for free as pdf too - they are perfectly legal to use. But quoting draft standards or using them as sources isn't formally correct.  In theory, contents could have changed from the draft to the final standard. Drafts are fine to use for the purpose of understanding C though (and good enough for SO). You only need the actual standards if you need to cite them from some kind of formal text, for example if you are writing a scientific study or a C programming book.

Comment: I've seen no evidence that the authors of C89 expected that the concept of "Undefined Behavior" would be interpreted to anything other than "Pick any course of action that would make sense given the target platform, code base (if any), and the purposes for which implementation is intended to be suitable."  In cases the standard describes as UB situations where it would almost always be obvious how implementation should behave, but there might be some rare cases where an implementer could have a good reason for doing something else.